# Get File Path(whole url in the site) by File Name in Cpanel Using php

Tags: php, file, cpanel

I want to get file path by giving a file name, i have seen code to get filename by filepath but i don't have the filepath, like for example if i give filename xyz.png it should give me the whole URL of the image like this: https://example.com/images/xyz.png, i am currently trying to do using cpanel.  is there a method for this in PHP:
for example: `get_file_url("xyz.png") // output: https://example.com/images/xyz.png`

Comment: Your question is not very clear - how does the code know where the image is?  If it is always in the same place, why not just do `echo 'https://example.com/images/' . $file`?

Comment: @Don'tPanic it's not in the same place, but i know the image name, i want to get the whole image url

Comment: OK, so *how does the code know where the image is?*  How will your code return the correct path? There is not enough info in this question for anyone to help.

Comment: @Don'tPanic that's what i am looking for, i want to know if i can get the path of image, i don't know. is there any method or function by using which the code can return the path of the image when it's name is given.

Comment: Your question really does not make much sense. Is there some pattern you can use to determine where the image is based on filename say?  Is the path saved in a database?  Do you want to scan the entire disk looking for the image every time you try to access it?  Edit your question, try to explain your question with some more detail, right now I don't think anyone has enough info to help you.